# Need to power 4 star mount LEDs

Tags: power-supply, led, led-driver

I have 4 of these

http://www.digikey.ca/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&itemSeq=233597054&uq=636360449794447719

These are star board mounted UVB LEDs ,I need to devise a way to power them in parallel or series, or combo, it doesnt matter whichever is cheapest. The Vf is 6.5v (min 5 max 8) and at 150mA
max power dissipation of 1.6 watts @ 200mA

So if I am correct I would need a 6.5v dc out , 600ma power supply for parallel Or in series a constant current 150ma 26v supply.  My source is 110v.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? The smallest thing I can find on ebay is 24v 1amp

Comment: Your digikey link is weird.

Comment: "My source is 110v" 110v dc or 110v ac?

Comment: _Any_ 110 Vac -> 150 mA constant current LED driver which can take an compliance voltage of 20-32 V would do the job.

Comment: RayVio Corporation RVXE-280-SB-071004  sorry about the link

Comment: 120vac   my bad   we used to  say 110/220  I guess the proper standard now is 120/240

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT wires your LEDs in parallel. Since all LEDs have a bit different voltage drops, the one with the lowest voltage drop will hog all the current, then burn. Then the next one will hog the current... etc.

Put them all in series. This way you only need one 150mA current source.

Your digikey link doesnt work, so I'll use your Vf data. For 4 LEDs in series we have:

min 20V
max 32V
typ 26V

So you need a 150mA constant current supply which can supply an output voltage between 20 and 26V.

There are lots of ready-made units for LED lighting. Check here for example:

http://www.meanwell.com/product/led/LED.html#non

If you cant find a 150mA one, pick a dimmable 350mA supply and dim it to 150 mA...

Comment: sorry about that,  dunno.  RayVio Corporation RVXE-280-SB-071004   is the actual part #

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 110V ac, this kind of thing should do the trick for you, this is 120V, not 110:

http://aceleds.com/admin/uploads/ac-5c150kb6_catalogspec.pdf

Connect the LEDs in series, not parallel, it's much easier that way.

Search for something like this:

LED constant current supply adjustable 100V

There are a plethora of this type of PSUs about.

Comment: So it looks like I am not going to be able to get around the parallel serial thing, I have 10 other diodes that run at 5v 600ma,  so if I put the 4 of these in a parallel circuit / and put that in series with the other diodes I get my 600ma (4x150) and 5v is the min vf for the 4 280nm diodes.

The diodes are all binned the same,  is there a way to create a parallel circuit that wont fail due to diff voltage drops?

Comment: Just don't go down the parallel route. I don't understand whay series is an issue for you.

Comment: trying to get everything on one driver

Comment: You just need to find a driver that will deliver your requisite current at the range of voltages your series string of LEDs need. It will exist - unless I am missing something here. Mind you, you suddenly seem to have moved the goalposts and added 10 more at 600mA.